# Multi Language website with Global Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resources

I have an website that contains 3 options idioms.

When User click in some button to change Idiom, I need change all Header and some texts to my GridView.

I made this option in my cs, but this translation works only on second click.

What could be wrong?

I made five labels to test, and all texts translated in first click.

I apply this option in other page, and also translated in first click.

My .aspx

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div  align="center">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="pt" ImageUrl="style/PT_48.png" runat="server" OnClick="pt_OnChange" OnClientClick="return pt_OnChange()" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:ImageButton ID="en" ImageUrl="style/EN_48.png" runat="server" OnClick="en_OnChange" OnClientClick="return en_OnChange()" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:ImageButton ID="es" ImageUrl="style/ES_48.png" runat="server" OnClick="es_OnChange" OnClientClick="return es_OnChange()" />
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="teste" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <div id="Div1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
            CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="idTickets" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessGroup" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FolderAccess" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SituationDesc" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Approver" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ApprovalDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessJustification" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Server" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserRequestor" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My .cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Idioma.MudaCultura(idiom);
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label2.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    Label3.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("welcome");
    Label4.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManager");
    teste.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("idTickets");
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("AccessGroup");
    GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("FolderAccess");
    GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("RequestDate");
    GridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
    GridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Approver");
    GridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ApprovalDate");
    GridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    GridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Server");
    GridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var listaTickets = new Tickets().ConsultarTickets();
        if (listaTickets != null)
        {
            this.GridView1.DataSource = listaTickets;
            if (listaTickets.Count != 0)
            {
                this.GridView1.DataBind();
                GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void pt_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    idiom = "pt";
    Idioma.MudaCultura(idiom);
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("idTickets");
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("AccessGroup");
    GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("FolderAccess");
    GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("RequestDate");
    GridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
    GridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Approver");
    GridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ApprovalDate");
    GridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    GridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Server");
    GridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label2.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    Label3.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("welcome");
    Label4.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManager");
    teste.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
}

protected void en_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    idiom = "en";
    Idioma.MudaCultura(idiom);
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("idTickets");
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("AccessGroup");
    GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("FolderAccess");
    GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("RequestDate");
    GridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
    GridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Approver");
    GridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ApprovalDate");
    GridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    GridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Server");
    GridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label2.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    Label3.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("welcome");
    Label4.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManager");
    teste.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
}

protected void es_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    idiom = "es";
    Idioma.MudaCultura(idiom);
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("idTickets");
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("AccessGroup");
    GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("FolderAccess");
    GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("RequestDate");
    GridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
    GridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Approver");
    GridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ApprovalDate");
    GridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    GridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Server");
    GridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");
    Label2.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    Label3.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("welcome");
    Label4.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManager");
    teste.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
}
```

My class with RetornaMensagem and MudaCultura.

public class Idioma
{
    private string chaveRM = "";

```
public string ChaveRM
{
    get { return chaveRM; }
    set { chaveRM = value; }
}

public static string RetornaMensagem(string NomeMensagem) 
{
    ResourceManager resx = new ResourceManager(typeof(RM)); 
    return resx.GetString(NomeMensagem, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture); 
} 

public static void MudaCultura(string cultura)
{ 
    if (cultura=="pt") 
    { 
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt", true); 
    } 

    else if(cultura=="en") 
    { 
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en", true); 
    }

    else if (cultura == "es")
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es", true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an solution with help to Nps. Before each event click to translate my page, I reload content from my GridView1. Below an example to event click in pt-BR translate.

```
protected void pt_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    idiom = "pt";
    Idioma.MudaCultura(idiom);
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("idTickets");
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("AccessGroup");
    GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("FolderAccess");
    GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("RequestDate");
    GridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("SituationDesc");
    GridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Approver");
    GridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ApprovalDate");
    GridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("BusinessJustification");
    GridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Server");
    GridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserRequestor");

    var listaTickets = new Tickets().ConsultarTickets();
    if (listaTickets != null)
    {
        this.GridView1.DataSource = listaTickets;
        if (listaTickets.Count != 0)
        {
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `GridView1.DataBind()` after updating the header.

Comment: Tks! But, just it not work! To working good I call all lines that run into my page_load, after my Update in Headers. I show my solution in an comment! But, I have to thank you because if you not shows your solution, I could not have building my solution. Sorry to my english...

Comment: Rather, create a common method that contains all translation and binding code.  This method will accept "idiom" as parameter.  It'll help to manage the code properly.